# discord.py logs how i can do that?

Tags: discord.py

Help me please, I want my bot to send logs (like **"user entered the channel"** and **"message deleted"**, **"user joined the server"**) thanks in advance

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message_delete(self, message):

        deleted = Embed(
            description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC
        ).set_author(name=message.author, url=Embed.Empty, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

        deleted.add_field(name="Message", value=message.content)
        deleted.timestamp = message.created_at
        await channel.send(embed=deleted)
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, you haven't told us what your problem is... although I do see that `channel` is undefined. You can define it using `channel = bot.get_channel(your_channel_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make an example, you want to make it log when a user joins. Sure thing, I personally use client, and without cogs so you can change it if you want to:

```py
@client.event
async def on_user_join(self, member):
    logs_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_HERE)
    logs_channel.send(f"{member} has joined")
    # you can change the welcome message of course that is an example
```