# How do I make an embed on user join in a certain channel in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was looking into building my own bot and I was wondering how I could make an embed that gets sent into a certain channel for every time that a user joins the server.

Comment: It's similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789258/discord-py-logs-how-i-can-do-that/66909231#66909231. Strange they didn't signal it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an event of some sort, as well as an embed that you'd want to send.

This covers those bases:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID_HERE)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=..., description=..., colour=...)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

---

### References:

- [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) - The event that triggers when a member joins the server.
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) - Getting the channel object in order to send the embed
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) - You can get some attributes for the `member` that joined, such as their profile picture, name etc.
- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed)